# Click li element programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to click a li tag when page loads but it is not working. 
HTML:

```
 <div id="listDiv">
    <ul id="listUL" class="listUL">
        <li id="f1" class="listDynamic">Term1</li>
        <li id="f2" class="listDynamic">Term2</li>
        <li id="f3" class="listDynamic" >Term3</li>  
    </ul>   
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#listUL").find("li#f1").click(function() {
                alert("clicked:" + this.id);
            });
$("#listUL").find("li#f1").trigger("click");

/*
 I also tried 
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#listUL").find("li#f1").trigger("click");
});

*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hx20d87m/4/

Comment: You needed to include jQuery in your jsfiddle on the left side like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hx20d87m/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("li#f1").click(function() {
        alert("clicked:" + this.id);
    });

    $("li#f1").trigger("click");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz8owa76/

Comment: Thank you sir for an quick response but it is still not working.. please file below.. thanks... http://jsfiddle.net/hx20d87m/7/

Comment: @user1546784 in your fiddle, you forgot to include jQuery.

Comment: Yes.. thank you for figguring out.. newbee error.. thanks.. veeTrain and Dmytro..

Answer (score 2):

If you interest do it via Javascript:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("listUL");
function Alert(){
  console.log(this.id);
  alert(this.id);
  }
console.log(list);
for(i=0;i<=list.childElementCount-1;i++){
  list.children[i].addEventListener("click",Alert);
  }
```

```html
<div id="listDiv">
    <ul id="listUL" class="listUL">
        <li id="f1" class="listDynamic">Term1</li>
        <li id="f2" class="listDynamic">Term2</li>
        <li id="f3" class="listDynamic" >Term3</li>  
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not need to use javascript. You can do like this in your css

```
li {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

and in the li tag you can use attribute `onclick` like this, and navigate to the file/page you want to go to in `location.href`

```
<div id="listDiv">
    <ul id="listUL" class="listUL">
        <li id="f1" class="listDynamic" onclick="location.href=`....`;">Term1</li>
        <li id="f2" class="listDynamic" onclick="location.href=`....`;">Term2</li>
        <li id="f3" class="listDynamic" onclick="location.href=`....`;">Term3</li>  
    </ul>   
</div>
```